# How to prevent Ruby on Rails Active record from getting default model values from the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, firebird

I'm developing a RoR app, with Firebird with its SQL engine but i cant understand why ActiveRecord (AR) keeps querying the database for default values!

Here is the tables DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE GLOBAL_SETTINGS
(
  SKEY varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  SVALUE varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  OBS blob sub_type 1,
  IS_SYSTEM "BOOLEAN" DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
  CREATED_AT timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_AT timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_SKEY PRIMARY KEY (SKEY)
);
```

Here is the migration that created this table: (`create_global_settings.rb`)

```rb
class CreateGlobalSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :global_settings, :id => false do |t|
      t.string :skey, :null => false, :limit => 64
      t.string :svalue, :null  => false, :limit => 256
      t.text :obs
      t.boolean :is_system, :null  => false, :default => true
      t.timestamps :null  => false
    end

    # defaults on timestamp columns
    execute("alter table GLOBAL_SETTINGS alter column CREATED_AT set default     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;")
    execute("alter table GLOBAL_SETTINGS alter column UPDATED_AT set default     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;")    

    # our custom PK naming
    execute("alter table GLOBAL_SETTINGS add constraint PK_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_SKEY primary     key (SKEY)")    
  end

  def down
    drop_table :global_settings
  end
end
```

Here is my model: (`global_Settings.rb`)

```
class GlobalSettings < ActiveRecord::Base
  #model validations!
  validates :skey, presence: true
  validates :skey, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, message: 'Global setting key     allready exists!'}

  validates :svalue, presence: true        
end
```

No views or tests or helper are defined!

In rails console if i do:

```
gs = GlobalSettings.new(skey: 'testKey', svalue: 'testValue')
D, [2014-11-21T13:11:18.547669 #7215] DEBUG -- :    (192.2ms)  SELECT CAST(1 AS SMALLINT)   FROM RDB$DATABASE
D, [2014-11-21T13:11:18.564272 #7215] DEBUG -- :    (16.3ms)  SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   AS TIMESTAMP) FROM RDB$DATABASE
D, [2014-11-21T13:11:18.580900 #7215] DEBUG -- :    (16.4ms)  SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP) FROM RDB$DATABASE
#<GlobalSettings skey: "testKey", svalue: "testValue", obs: nil, is_system: true,   created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
gs.save
D, [2014-11-21T13:11:24.403986 #7215] DEBUG -- :   GlobalSettings Exists (13.2ms)  SELECT    1 AS one FROM "GLOBAL_SETTINGS"  WHERE LOWER("GLOBAL_SETTINGS"."SKEY") = LOWER(?) ROWS 1,   testKey
D, [2014-11-21T13:11:24.543674 #7215] DEBUG -- :   SQL (89.4ms)  INSERT INTO   "GLOBAL_SETTINGS" ("CREATED_AT", "SKEY", "SVALUE", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), 2014-  11-21 13:11:24, testKey, testValue, 2014-11-21 13:11:24
true
```

As you can see it seems that AR is trying to get the default values for my model/table, and in this case that is not needed because it's querying the database 3 times, and it should only be doing an insert, and letting the SQL engine take care of the rest.
How do i prevent this kind of situation to happen?

Is there any way to prevent AR to fetch defaults for columns?

And another question, in the new method of the `GlobalSetting` model i am just using columns `sKey:` and `sValue:`, why is active record putting all others columns in the insert?

Comment: as for other columns in the insert  do you mean created_at and updated_at?  AR will maintain those columns if they exist,  your defaults that you add will only be used if things besides AR modify this table.

Comment: You mean that if i specify "t.timestamps :null  => false" in the migration, AR will always try to update/insert those column values, even if not specified? All other columns will remain untouched (unless directly specified)?

Comment: yes created_at, updated_at columns are magic. Even if you specify null: false in your migration, all that does is create a non null constraint in the DB, AR doesn't look at migrations it only looks at the DB.  AR will introspect the table, get all the columns and map them to your object. If it sees those columns it will automatically maintain them.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very mutch for that insight...
But it that case what is the "(192.2ms)  SELECT CAST(1 AS SMALLINT)   FROM RDB$DATABASE" line for? I thought is was for the "IS_SYSTEM" column that is a BOOLEAN domain (actually a smallint that can only assume 0 or 1)! But you say it on does that for "magic" columns, right?

Comment: AR needs to know the table layout, so it knows how to map them to the ruby object. As you are in development, with class reloading enabled it is going to do that often. to make sure it currently has the correct info.  In production it should only do it on first use and then cache the results for performance.  What you are seeing is AR trying to figure out how to map values between ruby and your DB.. This work is delegated down to he DB adaptor to implement as each DB is slightly different.

Comment: I need to check out fb-activerecord-adapter to understand what is happening...
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK: new only creates a model object which accepts a hash as a parameter in which keys are your table attributes. It does not query database at this point of time. Once you call the save method, it first calls valid? method to check if your object passes the validations you have defined. It is independent of database schema except for the uniqueness validation you have defined here. Uniqueness validation queries the database to check if such a value already exists. Once your object passes all the validations, it then calls the query to insert the data into your database. If the data violates some conditions at database level, exception is raised. So when the query is run at the database level, you have no control over it from rails. If there are default values in the database, they'll be assigned. The only way to bypass them is to explicitly passing some other values to the corresponding attribute.
And as per the behaviour of t.timestamps, yes, rails will automatically update the updated_at column each time you modify that record and created_at column when you create a new record.